# tf.lookup.StaticHashTable with lists (of arbitrary sizes) as values

Tags: python, tensorflow, dictionary, hashtable, lookup

I want to associate to each person's name a list of numbers.

```
keys = ["Fritz", "Franz", "Fred"]
values = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9]]
```

If I run the following:

```
import tensorflow as tf
table = tf.lookup.StaticHashTable(tf.lookup.KeyValueTensorInitializer(keys, values), default_value=0)
```

, I get a `ValueError: Can't convert non-rectangular Python sequence to Tensor.`
since the lists are not of the same size and hence cannot be converted to a `tf.Tensor`.

**Is there another way to associate the values of a tensor to lists of arbitrary shape?**

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`StaticHashTable` - as of TF 2.3 - cannot return multi-dimensional values, let alone ragged ones. So despite padding the values, creating a hash table like this:

```py
keys = ["Fritz", "Franz", "Fred"]
values = [[1, 2, 3, -1], [4, 5, -1, -1], [6, 7, 8, 9]]
table_init = tf.lookup.KeyValueTensorInitializer(keys, values)
table = tf.lookup.StaticHashTable(table_init, -1)
```

will throw the following error:

```
InvalidArgumentError: Expected shape [3] for value, got [3,4] [Op:LookupTableImportV2]
```

To circumvent this, you can use [Dense hash tables](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/lookup/experimental/DenseHashTable) although it is in experimental mode. Neither dense nor static hash tables provide support for ragged keys [or values](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/29529#issuecomment-635916245). So your best bet is to pad your values, and create a dense hash table. During lookup, you can rag them back. The overall code looks like this:

```
keys = ["Fritz", "Franz", "Fred"]
values = [[1, 2, 3, -1], [4, 5, -1, -1], [6, 7, 8, 9]]
table = tf.lookup.experimental.DenseHashTable(key_dtype=tf.string, value_dtype=tf.int64, empty_key="<EMPTY_SENTINEL>", deleted_key="<DELETE_SENTINEL>", default_value=[-1, -1, -1, -1])
table.insert(keys, values)
```

And during lookup:

```py
>>> tf.RaggedTensor.from_tensor(table.lookup(['Franz', 'Emil']), padding=-1)
<tf.RaggedTensor [[4, 5], []]>
```